# Citing an article that the journal serialized

Tags: publications, citations, citation-style

> Reynolds, Keld J. "Principal Actions of the California Junta De Fomento 1825-1827." Calif Hist QJ Calif Hist Soc 24.4 (1945): 289-320.
>
> Reynolds, Keld J. "Principal Actions of the California Junta De Fomento, 1825-1827 (Continued)." California Historical Society Quarterly 25.1 (1946): 57-78.
>
> ...
>
> Reynolds, Keld J. "Principal Actions of the California Junta De Fomento, 1825-1827 (Concluded)." California Historical Society Quarterly 25.4 (1946): 347-367.

This monograph was serialized in five quarterly installments. It was tricky to collate the parts using JSTOR, especially because none of the page numbers are consecutive. The middle three even have the same title, (Continued).

Should citing several elements of this paper produce multiple bibliography entries? I would rather be able to refer to it as a unitary work, but that work is a weirdly paginated, hypothetical one. If the answer is down to a difference between style standards, please indicate which styles those are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general rule is to always, always cite material as it is published, even if that somehow looks weird to you. This monograph has, for reasons we all can only speculate about, been split into 5 papers, so you cite it as if it were 5 papers. You **do not** pretend like it was somehow a single virtual paper. Even if the papers have partially the same name, at least the volume or issue number should be different. Yes, this will look like you have a duplicate entry in your bibliography to the casual observer, but I am afraid this can't be helped.

Further, note that you probably only need to cite a subset of these 5 installments. Again, treat them as different papers, and only cite the subset that actually contains arguments that are relevant to the article you are currently working on.

Comment: I may have to cite all five then. Shaking my fist at the editor that made the decision to serialize.